# Overflowing text from one Bootstrap row hides behind text of another row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Pardon my jargon, I just recently got into web development and have poor communication skills.

I'm using bootstrap 4 alpha and JQuery 3.

I have a chatroom within one fluid container with two rows: a send-message bar and a recieve message column(plus the pm column and userlist column)

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

   <!-- Chat View Column -->
   <div class="col-sm-2">
    <ul id="privateChats" class="list-group fixed" style=" margin-top:20px;">

    </ul>
   </div>

   <!-- Message View Column -->
   <div class="col-sm-8" style="float: left;">

    <ul class="" id="messages" style="margin: 20px;"></ul>

   </div>
   <!-- Connected Users Column -->
   <div class="col-sm-2">
    <ul id="connectedUsers" class="list-group fixed" style=" margin-top:20px">
     <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="width:100%">

     </div>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

        <!-- Send message bar -->
  <div class="row">
   <form action="">
   <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 text-right">
    <input type="text" id="m" style="width:100%; height:55px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" autocomplete="off" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-left">
    <button style="width:50%"><span class="fa fa-paper-plane" style="font-size:38px; color:white;"></span></button>
   </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

When the "Message View Column" fills up, text disappears behind the second row and I can't see the most recent messages. How do I fix this?

Let me know if I should add more detail

I added the Javascript tag because I'm not opposed to using Javascript to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `margin-bottom: 98px;` (height of the 2nd `.row`) to the css of the 1st `.row`, would solve your problem. Then you can use `scrollBy(0, 100)` to scroll the page to the bottom (used 100 as example)

Comment: Hm, better, but it doesn't work when I don't have the window super big. When the window is smaller, it still hides the newest message

Comment: didn't saw that case. so add `margin-bottom: 153px;` to the css of the 2nd `.row` and on the media queries `min-width .row` 768px and greater, add `margin-bottom: 98px`. if you want javascript, calculate the height of the 2nd row height with `$(".row form").css("height").replace("px", "")` and on the resize event, set the 1st row that calculated value. i recommend and prefer the css version

Comment: "so add margin-bottom: 153px; to the css of the 2nd .row" mistake: 1st `.row` not 2nd (can't edit my last comment)